# Should every class that is only used once be static?

Tags: c#, static

I've seen various discussions about this and I suppose it may be a bit opinion based, but what I'm trying to find out is if I know I will only use a class once (one instance), should I just make it static for convenience? Is that bad practice or will it create a problem?

For example. If I make a single player game, there will only be one player at all times. So do I make `public static class Player{}` or do I stick with `public class Player{}` `Player player = new Player();`

The idea is that this would save time by not needing to pass around references.

Comment: I assume you're looking for singletons, you can read more about it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Comment: it will not help performance that much. so if you are thinking that way just ignore it. your computer can pass a reference million times before you blink.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that there is a difference between using a class only once and using only one instance of a class (more on that below).

Static classes are usually classes whose purpose is to expose a set of functionalities and/or constants which are *independent* of each other *and do not need to maintain state information*. If this is what your class does then you can declare it as a static.

In your example, I do not think that this is the way to go. A `Player` object might have different states and other properties, such as location, health etc. The moment you try to have 2 players in the game then your design breaks.

Using only one instance of a class is usually achieved through the [`Singleton`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) design pattern. The aim of this pattern is to provide you with the *same instance* of a given object, regardless of how many times you actually make use of said object.

Answer (score 1):

It is bad practice. You don't know how your game will scale, so in some time you will decide to make abstractions behind your class and it will turn refactoring of code into hellpit.
If you, for example, decided what your **Player** is inherited from class **Human** or from some abstract class **VisibleObject** you will be stuck with dilemma.

So, when to use static? Primarly on methods, Extensions classes, some very simple fields and that's all.

Answer (score -1):

static class is basically same as other class but the difference is that you cannot instantiated.
In above example, it does not matter you use static class or not.